# AngularJS/Javascript ternary operator code explanation required

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, ternary-operator, deferred

I saw this code in Angular Material web site :

```
function querySearch (query) {
      var results = query ? self.states.filter( createFilterFor(query) ) : self.states,
          deferred;
      if (self.simulateQuery) {
        deferred = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function () { deferred.resolve( results ); }, Math.random() * 1000, false);
        return deferred.promise;
      } else {
        return results;
      }
    }
```

Can anyone explain whats happening here ?

if query is not null we call the filter otherwise we return the states and what is that **",deffered"** part ?

defered has not created yet and we can't return multiple values either!

So what is the explanation for this code ?

The code is here:
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete
The first one (Basic Usage)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is why ternaries are bad for readability. That comma has nothing to do with the ternary, since it's attached to a variable declaration.

All this is doing is declaring the (undefined) variable `deferred`.

You can declare variables multiple at a time with the comma syntax like so:

```
var x = 4,
    y = 7,
    z = Math.random();
```

Comment: Welcome to the world of job security, write code so bad and so complex they have no choice but keep you!

Comment: How can we sometimes return actual result and sometimes a promise ? How can we distinguish the result at the caller side?

Comment: You shouldn't force yourself into that situation. Since a good result is a promise, you should have your else return a `reject`ed Promise value, so that no matter what, the result can be `then`'d and it doesn't create a weird scope on your return value

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications.